# Did GitHub collaborate with Chinese authorities to remove the “#2020 nCov memory” page on GitHub?

Tags: china, covid-19, microsoft, censorship

The *#2020 nCov memory page* [[former URL](https://2019ncovmemory.github.io/nCovMemory/)] was a GitHub page. [Qz](https://qz.com/1811018/chinese-citizens-use-github-to-save-coronavirus-memories/) explains:

> The project, which was started by seven volunteers based around the world, chronicles and collects personal narratives and Chinese news reports on the disease. “The purpose of the page is to serve as a database for researchers, such as those studying epidemic prevention and natural language processing, as well as internet users,” said a notice on the GitHub page titled “#2020 nCov memory,” referring to the short form of novel coronavirus.

Joshua Phillip, on his YouTube Channel, *Cross Roads* [claims](https://youtube.com/watch?v=pQUYzPDI0w4&feature=youtu.be&t=7m) (starts at the 7 minute mark) that the site was taken down and the organizers were detained by Chinese authorities. He cites the South China Morning Post.

He then openly wonders (at 9 min 30 secs in):

> GitHub is run by Microsoft. Did Microsoft or GitHub cooperate with Chinese authorities in pulling down this page?

Is this the case?

Comment: It's a bit of a wishy-washy claim (in terms of notability), because he is careful not to stand behind it, but just point out that the question is raised. He is openly speculating.

Comment: Considering that, according to the accepted answer, the site *wasn't even removed*, any claim about who collaborated with whom for its removal is purely hypothetical.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The [Hong Kong Free Press reports](https://hongkongfp.com/2020/04/28/three-beijing-activists-missing-after-preserving-virus-articles-online/)

> The administrators of 2019nCoVMemory — another GitHub coronavirus archive — made the “protective” move to restrict access to its site to members only, according to an email sent to subscribers that was circulated on Weibo.

(I would have preferred to link directly to the email, but I am unable to find it due to language barriers.)

Meanwhile, on GitHub, there are plenty of [copies of the project](https://github.com/search?q=nCovMemory) that haven't been removed.

This would suggest that it was not an action by Microsoft or Github to remove the page.

Comment: The content of the email in Chinese was mentioned on [DW.com/zh](https://www.dw.com/zh/%E4%B8%AD%E5%9B%BD%E7%BB%AD%E6%89%93%E5%8E%8B%E6%96%B0%E5%86%A0%E8%A8%80%E8%AE%BA-%E5%8C%97%E4%BA%AC%E4%B8%89%E5%BF%97%E6%84%BF%E8%80%85%E9%81%AD%E6%8D%95/a-53255271). Unfortunately, I can't speak Chinese either, so, Google Translate'd: "*In order to circumvent the potential rules, we made the site privately visible and no longer public. We deeply regret this, but this measure is protective and all of our members are safe now. The situation permits, it does not rule out that the website will be reopened.*"